# If else - how to switch between two php files depending on the url

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

So, I would like to switch between 2 php files depending on the url. So far my code looks like this...

```
        <?php $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    if (strpos($url, "/ru/"))  {
       <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Tours-en')); ?>
    }else {
       <?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Tours-ru')); ?>            
    }  
    ?>
```

I don't know what should be before `<?php wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'Tours-en')); ?>` like `use <? php wp_nav_menu etc.`. I hope you see what is my problem. I don't know the name of the "command" which should be before `<?php`.

To clarify, the two php files between which I would like to switch contain menus.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $Path=$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking? Please clarify what you mean by 'I don't know the name of the "command" which should be before `<?php`'

Comment: Have you read up on `include()` ?

Comment: I think he's trying to load up different menus based on the current URL of the page, but I am not sure if that's what he wants. Let's wait for his clarifications.

Comment: Ali has it right. I would like to load different menus depending on the current URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
<?php 
    $url = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    wp_nav_menu(array(
              'theme_location' => (strpos($url, "/ru/"))?'Tours-en':'Tours-ru'
                      ));
?>
```

Comment: thanks, works grate. Actualy the menus are switched (when on russian site it shows english and on enlsh site it shows russain menus, but thats probably my mistake). Edit: I switched 'Tours-en':'Tours-ru' and it works perfectly now. So: `'theme_location' => (strpos($url, "/ru/"))?'Tours-ru':'Tours-en'` PS: Thanks for the fast responce